# Is it good practice to return in a try block?

Tags: java

I am curious about the best practice concerning having a return statement in a try block.

I have a method that calls a service method that returns an integer and potentially throws an IllegalArgumentException.  There are two ways to do this.

First:

```
public int getLookupStatus(String lookupType)
{
    try
    {
        return this.lookupService.getCountOfLookupRecords(lookupType);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException ex)
    {
        throw new RestException();
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public int getLookupStatus(String lookupType)
{
    int count;

    try
    {
        count = this.lookupService.getCountOfLookupRecords(lookupType);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException ex)
    {
        throw new RestException();
    }

    return count;
}
```

In the second approach, the count variable seems unnecessary, but the first approach seems wrong to me for some reason.  Is there any particular reason to favor one over the other?

Comment: The first code is more readable and the second probably does not compile.

Comment: @assylias: The second code should compile - `count` is still definitely assigned. I prefer the first too though.

Comment: @assylias The second should compile because `count` is a primitive. If it was something like `String`, it wouldn't.

Comment: It is perfectly alright to return from try block. Like others, I prefer first one. Prefer second one if you want to do something with the result before returning.

Comment: @VivinPaliath It has to do with definite assignement as pointed out by Jon, the code would also compile with an Object or String.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Why would it? The value is initialized at the successful completion `count =` line, whether it's an object or a primitive. And if that line doesn't complete, then the compiler knows that `throw New RestException()` will happen, thus preventing `return count`.

Comment: @yshavit Derp, you're right. Too early and I'm not thinking clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in returning value in `try` block, if the `IllegalArgumentException` was raised (or any other `RuntimeException`) you wouln't even return anything from that method, normal execution flow of the program will be changed due to that exeption.

Pattern from second example is used in cases when resource used/instantiated in catch block needs to be closed, then in `finally` clause you are handling this properly.

Answer (score 0):

I like the first version because it looks more readable. Also, if an exception was raised, then it wouldn't matter because control is going to exit the method anyway.

The only reason I would use the second pattern is if I wanted to do something with the return value before I return it.

On another note, your code would probably be better if you *didn't* handle `IllegalArgumentException`. There should be a way for you to validate the parameter *before* you call your method.

Answer (score 0):

Both method produce the same result and in both case a value will be return if no error or an exception will be thrown.

But persnnaly I prefer the first one, much more easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

What you should avoid is to use return in finally clause. In general both block should declare an exit. If in try you have return you should have also it in catch, in your case the second return was replaced with throw.

I will also go with first snipest as it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Both the approaches are eventually the same. You cannot throw a exception as well as return a value from a method. these two things will never happen together. You can either return some value or throw an exception.

In second approach, the **return count;** statement is necessary or else compiler will throw an error message. This is because, if your code does not encounter any exception, it must have return value as per your method prototype.

Both the apprroaches are same except that first directly returns the value, while the second stores it in a variable and returns the value of variable which is eventually the same as first.

One more thing, you have not declared and **throws clause** in your method defination, which indicates **RestException() is a unchecked exception.** Generally it is not good practice to throw unchecked exceptions as the calling method may not handle it. **I recommend you to throw a checked exception instead.**

Comment: The bit about unchecked exceptions is definitely subjective, context-specific and far from consensus.